Does Rom.8.11 teach sanctification, or glorification?
Romans 8:11 (KJV)  - But if the Spirit of him that raised up Jesus from the dead dwell in you, he that raised up Christ from the dead shall also quicken your mortal bodies by his Spirit that dwelleth in you.
Is there anyway to know if this scipture is speaking about the holiness in a believers life, by the power of the Spirit;  or is this scripture teaching the promise of a glorified body?

Romans 8:11 is talking about eternal life. Verse 10 first reminds us of our mortal bodies:

Even though your body is subject to death because of sin...

Then verse 11 reminds us what will happen after our death; just as Christ, we will come back to life, eternally.

He who raised Christ Jesus from the dead will also give life to your mortal bodies...

First, we die in the flesh. Then He will give life to our mortal bodies as He did with Christ.
Notice that giving life to our mortal bodies in the future, whereas the Spirit living in us in the present in verse 9:

if indeed the Spirit of God dwells in you...

Although we currently live with the Holy Spirit, Yahweh will give life to our dead bodies in the future; meaning it hasn't happened yet. That eliminated sanctification (set apart for God), which happens while we are alive.

Romans 8:11 can be viewed as containing elements of both sanctification and glorification, but the primary emphasis seems to lean towards the promise of glorification—namely, the resurrection of the believer's body. Let’s analyze it with reference to the verses you provided:
1. Romans 8:11 and the Concept of Glorification
The verse explicitly refers to God “quickening” or “giving life” to our mortal bodies through His Spirit. This wording aligns with the promise of a future bodily resurrection. Paul presents this as a future reality, suggesting that just as God raised Christ, He will also raise believers’ bodies by the power of the indwelling Spirit. This corresponds with glorification: the final transformation and resurrection of the body.
2. John 6:63
Jesus says, "It is the Spirit that gives life (τὸ πνεῦμά ἐστιν τὸ ζῳοποιοῦν); the flesh profits nothing." Here, Jesus contrasts the life-giving power of the Spirit with the insufficiency of the flesh, underscoring that spiritual life and resurrection are found in the Spirit. This can parallel Romans 8:11, affirming that the Spirit brings life both now (in terms of spiritual vitality) and ultimately in resurrection.
3. 1 Corinthians 15:45
Paul refers to Christ as the “last Adam,” a “life-giving Spirit” (πνεῦμα ζῳοποιοῦν), contrasting Him with the first Adam, who became a "living soul." This reinforces the theme of resurrection life through the Spirit, especially in the context of the glorified body that believers will receive, pointing towards a future, bodily glorification.
4. 2 Corinthians 3:6
Paul describes the Spirit as life-giving (τὸ δὲ πνεῦμα ζῳοποιεῖ) as opposed to the letter of the law, which “kills.” This life-giving power of the Spirit applies to the believer's current experience but also foreshadows the ultimate life-giving event: resurrection.
1 Peter 3:18
Christ was "put to death in the flesh, but made alive by the Spirit" (ζῳοποιηθεὶς δὲ πνεύματι). Here, Peter suggests that Christ's resurrection was accomplished by the Spirit, paralleling Romans 8:11 in portraying the Spirit as the power behind resurrection, thus emphasizing glorification.
In summary, Romans 8:11 primarily emphasizes glorification—the promise of resurrection and the future transformation of the believer's body through the Spirit. While sanctification (a transformed life empowered by the Spirit) is implicit in the broader context of Romans 8, the “quickening” of mortal bodies is a future-oriented promise tied more directly to glorification than to present-day sanctification.

I recently heard it explained as the believer is dead if his mind is after the flesh, meaning attempted sanctification through ritual law observance,  but through the spirit we may have life, given to our mortal  bodies i.e sanctification, because there are scriptures that say if we live in sin it is as we are dead1 Timothy 5:6 (KJV)  - But she that liveth in pleasure is dead while she liveth.
